# Visual Studio Express 2010 - WinForms application - Help making system.timers.timer

Tags: vb.net, winforms, timer

I asked this earlier but didn't get a solid answer.

I am making a program in Visual Studio Express 2010 to mimic the game Cookie Clicker for fun.

In cookie clicker, you can get items that automatically generate cookies every second. I'm using a basic forms application and am very new so I basically only know how to modify events.

The forms timer runs on the same thread as everything else on the form so making a forms timer will not work because it will not fire in the background (at least I can't manage to get it to)

I need help making a timer that runs on a separate thread that will loop every second so I can add the value of the cookies per second to the total value of the cookies whenever the timer fires.

My current code is:

```
Public Class window
Dim varcookies As Integer = 0
Dim varcps As Decimal = 0
Dim varclickercost As Decimal = 10
Dim varclicker As Integer = 0

Private Sub Cookie_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Cookie.Click
    varcookies = varcookies + 1
    Me.CookiesVal.Text = varcookies
End Sub

Private Sub window_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    Me.CPSVal.Text = varcps
    Me.CookiesVal.Text = varcps
    Me.btnclicker.Text = varclickercost
    Me.clock.Enabled = True
End Sub

Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnclicker.Click
    If varcookies >= varclickercost Then
        varcookies = varcookies - varclickercost
        varcps = varcps + 0.5
        varclicker = varclicker + 1
        varclickercost = varclickercost * 1.5
        Me.Clickers.Text = varclicker
        Me.btnclicker.Text = varclickercost
        Me.CookiesVal.Text = varcookies
        Me.CPSVal.Text = varcps
    End If
End Sub
```

End Class

I understand that there is no timer present in the code but that's because I have no clue as to how they work.

I'm really new to VB as you can tell so an ELI5 explanation would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A System.Timers.Timer will, in fact, run in the background. Subscribe to its Elapsed event:

```
Private Sub MyTimer_Elapsed(sender As Object, e As ElapsedEventArgs) Handles myTimer.Elapsed
 varcookies = varcookies + varcps
End Sub
```

This subroutine is called whenever the timer reaches its designated period (in your case, 1 second). No need for you to make a separate thread, it does this automatically. Just make sure to set its Interval property to 1 second, and set Enabled to true in your form's Load.

Comment: hmmmm when I insert that code after creating a timer, it underlines the .elapsed part in the handles and says event elapsed cannot be found. When run I get "Unable to cast object of type 'System.EventArgs' to type 'System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs'." error

Comment: Are you using a System.Timers.Timer or a System.Windows.Forms.Timer? My answer covers the System.Timers.Timer; System.Windows.Forms.Timer calls its event Tick (so write `Handles myTimer.Tick` and `e As EventArgs`) but the principle should be the same.

Comment: Yeah, I'm new so I used the drag and drop timer control. Now my problem is making the store labels "?????" before the cookies are at a certain value. I'm having a problem doing this and apparently the solution from google is breakpoints which are only available in c++ .-. I'm trying to make it recursively read an If or While statement but whenever I add it to the timer loop, it breaks the application

Comment: I don't think that you should add this to the timer loop. I would make varcookies a property so that you can check if it's greater than a certain value and change the text of the store labels _whenever varcookies is changed_, instead of every second. Here's some more on [properties](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bc3dtbky.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

You should not be using a timer on a separate thread for such a simple task. Just add a Timer to your main form by dragging the Timer entry from the Toolbox and dropping it on your Form. Then select it in the Properties window and set it to tick every 1000ms and double click the timer at the bottom of the form in order to add an event handler that is fired every 1000ms.

Comment: wtf got "    Private Sub mytimer_Tick(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles mytimer.Tick
        varcookies = varcps + varcookies
        Me.CookiesVal.Text = varcookies
    End Sub" to work even though it was the first thing I tried. Thanks for the help you and apt-get, the first time I tried it, the counter only raised whenever I clicked the button and then thee value would jump.